# error 2676 during compilation when I insert values in the map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I'm making a checkers game in C++.

I have a class Board with a locationSquareMap map object.

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include "Square.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Man.h"
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<Square*> Column;

class Board
{
   const int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
   std::vector<Column> squares;
   std::map<Location, Square*> locationSquareMap; 

public:
    Board();
    ~Board();
    //Board(Board& board);
    void printBoard();
};

#endif
```

When I do nothing on locationSquareMap program compiles successfully.

```
#include "Board.h"

Board::Board() 
{   
    //locationSquareMap
for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
{
    squares.push_back(Column());
    for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
    {
        Location currentLocation(File(column), row);
        SquareColor currentSquareColor = SquareColor::WHITE;
        if ((column + row) % 2 == 0)        
        {
            currentSquareColor = SquareColor::BLACK;
        }
        Square* currentSquare = new Square(currentLocation, currentSquareColor);
        //locationSquareMap.insert(std::make_pair(currentSquare->getLocation(), currentSquare));
        //works fine without refering to the locationSquareMap
        squares.at(row).push_back(currentSquare);
    }
}   
}

Board::~Board()
{

}

void Board::printBoard()
{
    for (int i = squares.size() - 1; i != -1; i--)
    {
        for (int g = squares.at(i).size() - 1; g != -1; g--)
        {
            std::cout << *(squares.at(i).at(g)) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "    ";
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
    {
           switch (File(i))
           {
           case File::A : std::cout << "A "; break;
           case File::B : std::cout << "B "; break;
           case File::C : std::cout << "C "; break;
           case File::D : std::cout << "D "; break;
           case File::E : std::cout << "E "; break;
           case File::F : std::cout << "F "; break;
           case File::G : std::cout << "G "; break;
           case File::H : std::cout << "H "; break;
           default: std::cout << " "; break;
           }
       }
       std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
       for (int i = squares.size() - 1; i != -1; i--)
       {
           std::cout << i << "   ";
           //for (int g = squares.at(i).size() - 1; g != -1; g--)
           for(int g = 0; g < squares.at(i).size(); g++)
           {
               if (squares.at(i).at(g)->getColor() == SquareColor::BLACK)
               {
                   std::cout << "B ";
               }
               else
               {
                   std::cout << "W ";
               }
           }
           std::cout << std::endl;
       }
   }
```

But when I try to insert the values into the map I have the C2676 error in the completely another place.

```
for(int g = 0; g < squares.at(i).size(); g++)
    {
        if (squares.at(i).at(g)->getColor() == SquareColor::BLACK)
        {
            std::cout << "B ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "W ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

That's very strange because map does nothing with this loop.

Compilation error is following:

`Error  C2676   binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   Checkers3.0 C:\VisualStudio2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstddef   127`

Comment: If you want to use `Location` as a key then you need to tell the map how to sort it. An easy way is to provide `operator <` as mentioned in the error message.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thank you, worked out for me. Didn't know that for map implementation I have to set comparing rules by myself.